# why do software companies only typically have one or two related software offerings?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

I really wish there was more freedom and more products being made. Instead of devoting more hours of effort to a product that is already producing money, why not start development on another project rather than having engineers be stuck doing maintenance and minimal changes because that is what their team is assigned to do?

am I strange to think that a software company should produce at least one new product per year in addition to working on their current stuff?

I am tempted to go to a gaming company cause I know there would be constant new projects there, but I am nervous about the 60 hour work weeks.

I feel like too much of my time is not being utilized for purposes useful to my company, but I can't really go over my manager's head either...

sigh

Comment: This is really more of the starting point of a discussion then an answerable question so it's off topic here. It doesn't really fit on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) either. It might be suitable for a chat room there.

Comment: I work at a software company with essentially one product. Quite simply, it doesn't do everything it could do and our customers want it to do more. We want to keep those customers. It would be insane for us to start a new product line. There is no shortage of work to do, and it is neither minimal nor maintenance (much to our chagrin, it would be nice to have time to pay off some tech debt). Your view of how software works is skewed.

Comment: If they had an idea for a PROFITABLE project each year then I'm sure they'd do it. Even hiring more and more developers, if required. Without that a company won't even start to consider a new development because the target is not "to do something" but to have a profit. Games have a completely different life cycle but I strongly suspect each "new project" isn't what you expect it to be.

Comment: If you could manage to push out a new unique product, 100% bug free with all the features your customers need and want, I'm sure every company would do it. But applications are rarely bug free and have all the features from initial release while working cross platform, behind different networks and different architectures from the get go. Commercial software simply has a much larger scope to deal with than a single game, and you as the vendor are responsible for it.

Comment: this last comment makes a lot of sense. that is definitely one harder part about software. I just feel like management needs improvement here. my last job was so much more coordinated...I felt like 80-90% utilized there, so if there was downtime, I didn't mind so much. here, I feel like they have unclear goals and plans and underutilize the development team. I feel like they are getting about 30% of the value out of the developers that I would get if I were in charge, and I don't even know how to manage people

Comment: Note that of the reasons gaming companies have 60 hour work weeks is _because_ they launch so many new products ;-)

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet, poor management does exist and it can really make a job not-fun. Have you considered that your frustrations may be because you are working at a bad company and it is time to move on?

Comment: Erik they do 60 hours a week because they find young impressionable people, exploit them, suck them dry, and spit them out.

Comment: Software is never "done", it is merely "abandoned".

Comment: I worked at very good companies in the US, but I wanted to move to korea to be near friends. It's not nearly as easy for me to find a job over here in korea.  Not sure how feasible it is to find a european or US company that would let me work remote from korea either. I tried to look for that once about 2-3 years back but didn't have any luck. I'm at about 4 years of exp as a developer now.  it's definitely a far cry here from the level of management at my last 2 companies though

Answer (score 3):

Many companies are risk averse. They have a product that is making revenue. Even after paying teams of developers, they are still making money.

As you put it, the company has two options.

1. Continue doing maintenance on existing products.
2. Do minimal maintenance, and work on new products.

While 2 may have potential for a new revenue stream, it is not guaranteed. It is also not always as easy as just creating a new product. Support / Sales / Documentation is also required, and setting all of that up well is a huge effort. Developers aren't cheap, and if after all of that work it does not pay off, that would not sit well with the company. The manager who made that decision certainly wouldn't be in good standing either.

The benefits of 1 are that the current revenue stream would increase (or be less likely to fall). While some of the development may bring in new customers (customer acquisition) due to small new features, a major part of the maintenace is to keep their current customers (customer retention). It would also not sit will with the company if they lost a significant portion of their revenue trying to chase another revenue stream by starting another project.

While it could very well be profitable to start new projects, there is a risk involved, and there are situations to where it does not make sense to take that risk.
Of course, there are situations to where it would be the preferable thing to do, so if you really want to work on new projects often, you may want to look for a company with several smaller products.

Comment: I like this answer, but additionally, a significant benefit of 1) is much lower known costs (maintenance), therefore more predictable cashflow. Another risk of 2) is that if the new product supercedes the old, new customers will wait for it rather than buying the older one now, and any customer which buys old a month before new is released will be immediately hostile.

Comment: My company’s customers pay monthly. Doesn’t matter if they start a contract one month before the next release, they pay monthly and always get the latest release at no extra cost.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, but if you left bugs in there, or stopped adding new features that your competitor added in last month, they may not stay with you the next month.